# Progress Update Message only to an Open Tab (unique Connectionid) | SignalR

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr

I have been doing a lot of research on finding a working example of SignalR implementation where status updates are sent **only** to an instance of a browser tab. My application extracts web data, and that process takes a lot of time.

I have been able to send status updates, but only to all users that have the webpage open.

```
//Server side (works just fine)
public class SendCustomText : Hub
{
    public string myStatus;
    public void CurrentStatus()
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SendCustomText>();
        context.Clients.All.setStatus(myStatus);
    }
}

//Client side
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //Declare a proxy to the reference hub
    var currentStatus = $.connection.sendCustomText;
    currentStatus.client.setStatus = function (value) {
        $('#signalr_french_status').text(value.toString());
    }
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('pandora_french_panel_extract_button').click(function () {
            currentStatus.server.send();
        })
    })
    $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    })
})
```

What I, however, need is a way to update progress only in a tab that is open. The logged-in user may open another tab and process another job, and that new tab should display its own progress.

I did try successfully getting the connection ID client side and then passing it through AJAX to the server code. I need your help with an example where connection ID is used in the hub.

```
context.Clients.Client(connectionID).setStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem myself. (I had made a very basic error initially. The first time, I used `public string myConnectionID`, that is, without the `static` keyword.)

```
public class SendCustomText : Hub
{
    public string myStatus;
    public static string myConnectionID;

    public void CurrentStatus()
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SendCustomText>();
        context.Clients.Client(myConnectionID).setStatus(myStatus);
    }
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        myConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId;
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```